# cannot navigate through table of contents easily with Jupiter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have a fresh installation of anaconda 2023.09, in the jupiter lab environment, in my previous experience, in the context of table of contents, I can use left arrow and jump towards to current heading. Clicking left again will collapse the heading... but this suddenly does not happen. What can I do to make it happen again? Thanks!